# Passing clicked links to session array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, session

I have a problem passing clicked values to session array.
When I click the links below the class "is-active", so based on the active links I want to pass data to session. The idea is like the website: [newfuturescareernavigator.org/assessment/step-1/](http://newfuturescareernavigator.org/assessment/step-1/) which goes in three pages without Form.

```
<a href="#" data-chng="this is-active" data-id="190">
<a href="#" data-chng="this is-active" data-id="436">
<a href="#" data-chng="this is-active" data-id="430">
```

Here is after I click on the links, is activated the class is-active.

```
<a href="#" data-chng="this is-active" data-id="190" class="is-active">
<a href="#" data-chng="this is-active" data-id="436" class="is-active">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to just add the class (in javascript) or use ajax and store this in `$_SESSION` (php)? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to get data-id from selected links, but I can't do with ajax.

    <?php
    // Start the session
    session_start();

    // create an array
    $my_array=array('4', '3', '7', '6', '11');

    // put the array in a session variable
    $_SESSION['selectedvalues'] = $my_array;
    ?>

Comment: Why can't you use ajax, you put it as a tag for your question? You can store arrays in `$_SESSION`. You'd get the array from `$_GET` or `$_POST`. You should edit your question and include any code you've tried. If you don't need to store values server-side, you can just use javascript with onclick events.

Comment: I mean, I can't do with ajax, don't have so much experience.

Comment: did you try to use a label with a hidden checkbox and then get the results in next page? [check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svodmdr3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd be better off just capturing which links where clicked on the client side and then when the user proceeds to the "next step", you can handle the clicked links accordingly.

if you're absolutely set on doing it by saving which links are clicked in a session (upon the click), you'll have to use an ajax request to the server as session variables are server side.  Are you using JQuery or some other library that can help assist with this?

here's a quick sample for saving which links are clicked (w/o jquery).  Obviously, you'd need to write something to prevent the same link from being duplicated in the string and maybe something to remove a link.

```
    <body>
<input type="hidden" id="ClickedLinks" name="ClickedLinks" value="" />
<a href="#" onclick="clickMe(this)" id="link1">click me</a>
<a href="#" onclick="clickMe(this)" id="link2">click me</a>

<script>
function clickMe(obj) {
    clickedLinks = document.getElementById("ClickedLinks");
    if(clickedLinks.value == "") {
        clickedLinks.value = obj.id;
    } else {
        clickedLinks.value = clickedLinks.value +","+obj.id;
    }
    alert(clickedLinks.value);
}
</script>
</body>
```

EDIT: 
just wrap the html above in a form and have that form submit to your next step.  Once you're on the next step page just throw the value of ClickedLinks into a Session.

IE:

```
$_SESSION["ClickedLinks"] = $_POST["ClickedLinks"];
```

Comment: On the website [newfuturescareernavigator.org/assessment/step-1/][1] they don't use input. So I'm trying to do the things like a website above.

Comment: then use a JS variable in the global scope.  I put it in an input so it could be retrieved on the next step (when the form is submitted).

Comment: I will try, that is interesting why don't use forms, maybe they are using ajax to pass data to session!

Comment: I looked (briefly) at the site you linked.  They are making a request when the link is clicked, to a different page, that is passing the "clicked links" in the header of the request as a pipe delimited variable called "id".  Download fiddler and you can see it.  It's basically the same concept as what's in my answer, but making another (unnessesary) trip to the server.  You'd be better off just using a form and passing your data that way.

Comment: So can you give me one example how to make it happen, an easy solution?

Comment: I just added more to my answer with a way you can handle it on the server side once the form is submitted to the next step.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't take both links, only one link. How can I save it on array. Because I have so multiple clicks.

Comment: you can use explode() to turn it into an array and then just append to the array after the 2nd page is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

if you are posting to another page you can just use a `form` and then get the results with `$_POST`...

[See this example](https://jsfiddle.net/svodmdr3/)

HTML

```
 <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name='item1'>
      <span>Item 1</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name='item2'>
      <span>Item 1</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name='item3'>
      <span>Item 3</span>
    </label>
```

CSS

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

label input {
  /* display: none; */
}

input:checked ~ span {
  background: orange;
  color: #000;
}
```

Comment: I think it is good idea, just I wanted to keep the design as it is. But finally it is better to go with this way. So I have three pages, and need to collect the data for Selecting a query.